# Cannot change the text color of Angular material input placeholder

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am trying to change the placeholder text color on an Angular Material input. Appears to default to black but I want it to be white due to having a dark background color.

I have read probably every post on this site on how to do this but nothing seems to work. ::ng-deep and mat-placeholder are not options.

Here is a snippet from my HTML:

```
    <form #searchForm="ngForm" class="example-full-width mr-auto">
      <mat-form-field style="width: 350px; font-size: 14px; margin-bottom: -15px;">
        <mat-label style="color: white;">Search for an Employee</mat-label>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="userIdInput" placeholder="Enter at least 2 characters of a name or ID"
```

Comment: Have you checked in the debugger? Is there another setting with `!important` that is overriding? Is the actual label some child element that has its own stylings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Material Chips placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55103026/angular-material-chips-placeholder)

Comment: You may refer to the above link. The placeholder colour is dependent on the very same class, `mat-form-field-label`

Comment: The mat-form-field-label class does not work. I do have the ViewEncapsulation.None already set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change the css of your `placeholder`, all you need to do is modify the color of your `matInput` placeholder. You can make use of the `mat-input-element` class in the `matInput` element to do this.

Ideally, I would also suggest you avoid using inline styles and use classes instead. It makes your code more readable as well.

**HTML**

```
<form #searchForm="ngForm" class="example-full-width mr-auto">
  <mat-form-field class="employee-search-field">
    <mat-label>Search for an Employee</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="userIdInput" name="userIdInput" placeholder="Enter at least 2 characters of a name or ID"/>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

In your css, add the below code.

```
.employee-search-field {
  width: 350px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.employee-search-field mat-label {
  color: white;
  /* add label text color here */
}

.employee-search-field .mat-input-element {
  color: white;
  /* add input text color here */
}

.employee-search-field .mat-input-element::placeholder {
  color: white;
  /* add placeholder css here */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Search for an employee</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Enter at least 2 characters of a name or ID">
  </mat-form-field>
```

```
.mat-form-field {
  width: 350px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

::ng-deep .mat-input-element::placeholder {
  color: orange;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-form-field-label {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this method and it does not work. Also, ::ng-deep is supposed to be deprecated.